# Is there a way to make an array of rectangles?

Tags: lua, marmalade

I am using Marmalade Quick.

I can draw a rectangle with:

```
local myRectangle = director:createRectangle(x, y, width, height)
```

Is there a way to store the `myRectangle` variable in an array for later use? Or how can I make multiple rectangles and have access to each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yeah, just use lua tables.

```
local rects = {}
local myRect = director:createRectangle(x, y, width, height)
table.insert(rects, myRect)
```

now, if you want to examine all of your rectangles you can just iterate over `rects`.

if you absolutely have to store all of your references to rectangles, i'd suggest making a helper method to automate that part for you, something like this maybe:

```
local rects = {}
function createRect(x, y, width, height)
    local rect = director:createRectangle(x, y, width, height);
    table.insert(rects, rect)
    return rect
end
```

and then you could just call your helper function and know that each rectangle object it returns to you has automatically been added to your list for later.

```
local myRect = createRect(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a table

```
myRectangles = {}
```

and add the rectangles on to the end of the table as they are created.

```
myRectangles[#myRectangles+1] = director:createRectangle(x1, y1, width1, height1)
myRectangles[#myRectangles+1] = director:createRectangle(x2, y2, width2, height2)
```